# Spring AOP AsjectJ annotations : define pointcut for multiple methods

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I have defined by advise to be executed for the two methods :

**SampleBusinessLogicImpl.updateSample(Sample sample)** and
**SampleBusinessLogicImpl.createSample(Sample sample)**

But my advise get executed for the first update() method only.
What am I doing wrong here ?

```
@Aspect
public class SampleDynamicValidationAspect {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SampleDynamicValidationAspect.class); 

    /**
    private SampleTblDAO dao; //DAOs can be used inside dynamic validations
    **/


    @Before("execution(public * com.rakuten.gep.sample.businesslogic.impl.SampleBusinessLogicImpl.updateSample(com.rakuten.gep.sample.entity.common.Sample,..)) && args(sample,..) throws *Exception"
            +"|| execution(public * com.rakuten.gep.sample.businesslogic.impl.SampleBusinessLogicImpl.createSample(com.rakuten.gep.sample.entity.common.Sample,..)) && args(sample,..) throws *Exception")
    public void validate(Sample sample) throws SampleException {
        //Dynamic validation here.
        //If some validation is failed, wrapped the appropiate exception in SampleException
        System.out.println("Involking Dynamic Validator");
    }
}
```

My SampleBusinessLogicImpl class is as follows :

```
@Service
public class SampleBusinessLogicImpl implements SampleBusinessLogic {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value="proxySampleTblDao")
    private SampleTblDao sampleTblDao;

    @Override
    @Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class)
    public Sample createSample(Sample sample) throws SampleException {
        //..
    }


    @Override
    @Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class)
    public Sample updateSample(Sample sample) throws SampleException {
      //..

    }
}
```

Comment: Can we see your `SampleBusinessLogicImpl` class?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis i posted the code.

Comment: I find it easier to use custom annotations to mark where I want my pointcuts to be applied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you define the matching method expression in the `Pointcut`, it should match the actual method on which you would want to `advice`

This is what your pointcut expression should be

```
@Before("execution(public * com.rakuten.gep.sample.businesslogic.impl.SampleBusinessLogicImpl.updateSample(com.rakuten.gep.sample.entity.common.Sample,..) throws *Exception) && args(sample,..)"
            +"|| execution(public * com.rakuten.gep.sample.businesslogic.impl.SampleBusinessLogicImpl.createSample(com.rakuten.gep.sample.entity.common.Sample,..) throws *Exception) && args(sample,..)")
```

> **Reason:**

In your case, the method signature is

```
public Sample createSample(Sample sample) throws SampleException {
public Sample updateSample(Sample sample) throws SampleException {
```

But, your pointcut is

```
@Before("execution(public * com.rakuten.gep.sample.businesslogic.impl.SampleBusinessLogicImpl.updateSample(com.rakuten.gep.sample.entity.common.Sample,..)) && args(sample,..) throws *Exception"
            +"|| execution(public * com.rakuten.gep.sample.businesslogic.impl.SampleBusinessLogicImpl.createSample(com.rakuten.gep.sample.entity.common.Sample,..)) && args(sample,..) throws *Exception")
```

Notice that the `throws *Exception` is outside the method declaration in the `pointcut` expression. And that is why the pointcut expression doesnt match your method declaration. 
Move the `throws *Exception` within `execution(` and it will work. I just tried it.

**Clarifying the invocation of only one method.**

Yes, actually.. You do not need to specify the `throws *Exception`. It would suffice with just the method So, if you remove it completely, it would work perfectly fine, with both the method executions. Now, why update works is because, it is declared first in the `Pointcut` expression. So, the Pointcut matches the method declaration for `updateSample()` then it encounters the out of place `*Exception` and the || is applied to `*Exception` which actually is nothing.

Now, if you just flip the pointcut expression the way it is declared, the erroronous one that is. Only `createSample` would work because that is what the only one matched in the pointcut expression. 
Remember, the `)` is closed in the `execution expression` too.

```
@Before("execution(public * com.rakuten.gep.sample.businesslogic.impl.SampleBusinessLogicImpl.createSample(com.rakuten.gep.sample.entity.common.Sample,..) throws *Exception) && args(sample,..)"
            +"|| execution(public * com.rakuten.gep.sample.businesslogic.impl.SampleBusinessLogicImpl.updateSample(com.rakuten.gep.sample.entity.common.Sample,..) throws *Exception) && args(sample,..)")
```

Also, from the Spring AOP documentation

`execution(modifiers-pattern? ret-type-pattern declaring-type-pattern? name-pattern(param-pattern)
          throws-pattern?)`

All parts except the returning type pattern (ret-type-pattern in the snippet above), name pattern, 
and parameters pattern are optional.

Hope, i was able to help with the doubt.

Comment: Can you explain `my advise get executed for the first update() method only`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis. Couldnt type it all here :) So, updated the answer trying to clarify the doubt.

Comment: without "*Exception" it will work however , if an exception is thrown from the advise it will be wrapped inside , "UndeclaredThrowableException" exception.With "*Exception" if will throw the correct SampleException .

Comment: Correct, and that was your requirement hence i havent suggested to remove the `*Exception`, rather just pull it inside the `execution` expression

Answer (score 2):

You can define like this

```
@Before(value="( execution(* com.rakuten.gep.sample.businesslogic.impl.SampleBusinessLogicImpl.updateSample(..))"
    + "|| execution(* com.rakuten.gep.sample.businesslogic.impl.SampleBusinessLogicImpl.createSample(..)))"
    + " && args(sample)")
```